# How to get MAC address of a client device with connect mobile data in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, .net, networking, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

In my client-server-solution I need the MAC addresses of frontend devices, running my Xamarin.Forms app. Currently I just have get Mac Address connected by `Wifi` is correct in info about device. But, I used `mobile data` then get Mac Address in device not correct.

```
var lstAllNetWorkInfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
                        var ni = lstAllNetWorkInfaces.FirstOrDefault(intf => (intf.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
                                                             && (intf.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211
                                                                 || intf.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet));
                        var hw = ni.GetPhysicalAddress();
                        physicalWifiAddress = string.Join(":", (from ma in hw.GetAddressBytes() select ma.ToString("X2")).ToArray());
```

Please let me know if there's a bug or if you found a better solution.

Comment: Are the client and the server on the same network?

Comment: Hello, what is the MAC used for?

Comment: Your machine has a ARP table.  Try cmd.exe >ARP -A.ARP table has the MAC address. ARP table get updated when any machine sends an ARP message in the local Network which occurs when the machine is turned on and on a regular schedule like every 15 minutes.The table is also updated when a ping is performed on a machine not in the subnet.The response of a pin also contains the MAC.  You get physicalAddress() method reads the ARP table.  If the table does not contain the IP address for a machine then you have to ping the device.  Most likely you are not getting MAC becauwe machine is not in subnet.

Comment: @Cleptus Hi, I want get MAC address in tablet with connected by mobile data then client and the server not the same network.

Comment: @- g_bor Hi, I use MAC to manage the device tablet android on the server

Comment: I wonder if 3G networks do have ARP at all... I mean, they probably handle OSI layer 2, but if it is handled not using ARP but other protocol, you will not have MAC addresses... And I have no info in one way or another

Comment: "_I want get MAC address in tablet with connected by mobile data then client and the server not the same network._" MAC addresses are only seen or relevant on the network where the device is connected, not on a remote network. Security by MAC address is a fool's game because it is so easy to change a MAC address to spoof a valid one.

Answer (score 0):

"*Layer 2 (Data Link) - It provides a reliable signaling link between the mobile station (MS) and the network. Protocol is based on the LAPDm of ISDN*"

Source is [Does the OSI model also apply to mobile networks?](https://qr.ae/pNmUzQ).

So in 2G networks ARP is not used so MAC addresses are not a thing in that scenario. You should consider other client authentication method.

I would suggest client side certificates, they work in any device.